# Python installation cannot run C compiled programs on Debian 9

Tags: c, linux, gcc, debian, python-3.7

I'm trying to install Python 3.7 on my Linux machine, but it's telling me it's unable to run C compiled programs:

```cpp
root@kvm-RPJared2:~/Python-3.7.3# sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for python3.7... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/root/Python-3.7.3':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
root@kvm-RPJared2:~/Python-3.7.3# gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

As you can see, I already have GCC installed, so I'm a bit lost on how to solve this issue.

Edit: I've already tried to download directly from git using `apt-get`, but the program is running into trouble with invalidated GPG keys. I've also tried using `make` as a different su, and that runs into the same error as I've shown above. If anyone has answers to either the `apt-get` issue (`--allow-inauthenticated` hasn't worked either) or the error I've pasted above, please help me out!

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to compile python instead of using `apt-get` to install it?

Comment: I plan to follow `--enable-optimizations` with `sudo make altinstall`, I'm guessing that an `apt-get` installation might circumvent the problem I'm having entirely?

Comment: I'd say that unless you have a specific reason to recompile Python, you're better off using what's in the apt repository.

Comment: Will do, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Using `sudo ./configure` is wrong. All build steps except `make install` should not be done as root.

Comment: I tried to install Python as a new user, but I encountered the same error; on the other hand, using the apt repository isn't working out because I'm missing GPG keys and can't seem to bypass this issue using `--allow-inauthenticated`.